# Where to put startup and startup.auth code on .net framework (not .net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have this code:

https://github.com/nbarbettini/SimpleTokenProvider/tree/master/test/SimpleTokenProvider.Test

Which was done with .net CORE, its a WEB API with .net CORE.

I need to implement a WEB API with the same security, but with .net framework not dot net core.

Where do I need to put the code from Startup.cs, StartupAUth.cs, Program.cs in a classic asp.net web api project with .net framework 4.5.2?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a classic asp.net web project you will likely find the following locations in the `Global.asax.cs` file useful:

1) The `Application_Start` method is called once on application start and is useful for configuration code that only needs to run one per web server recycle.

2) The `Application_AuthenticateRequest` method is called once for every request and can be useful for authentication code, however be aware that it does not have access to session state.

3) The `Application_AcquireRequestState` method is called shortly after `Application_AuthenticateRequest` and can be useful for security related logic that needs access to session state.

These three should be able to provide you with the hooks you need to bring the functionality over.  However, you won't be able to use the same code as you are using in asp.net core because the architecture and available objects are different between the two platforms. So for example and `HttpRequest` object in Asp.Net Core is a different object (defined in a different namespace) than the `HttpRequest` object in full framework Asp.Net.

The concepts are similar in many cases (like HttpRequest) which helps with porting code, but it would be a porting exercise as the methods and properties on the objects are not identical.

Comment: I found that in classic asp.net you can also use Owin Middleware with a nugetpackage and then the startup class works also fine after installing the packages. Thanks

Comment: @LuisValencia, do you have any documentation for this?